# AutoLayout troubles

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

So i have five UIButtons in a UIView subclass. The five buttons are placed in a line. The first and the last button are pinned to the edges, while the third button is aligned horizontally to the superview. I want the second and the third button to be equidistant from the surrounding buttons at all times. How should I accomplish this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I dragged the constraints as IBOutlets and then calculated the distance between the buttons and set the half of the distance to the leading and the trailing constraints.

Comment: Another way would be to add some empty ui objects in between the buttons as spacing objects, set their size constraints to be equal to each other and connect the edges to the edges of the buttons.

Comment: Can i have link for tutorial for both of yours methods I want to try them